# Spring Data Couchbase: projections with reactive repository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

Reactive Couchbase repository with a method using DTO projections fails with

```
CouchbaseQueryExecutionException: Query returning primitive got more values than expected: 5
```

Is DTO projection supported by reactive repositories?

I'm trying to implement a very basic DTO projection repository method with a reactive repository: I have two Couchbase @Documents, and an interface representing a projection. A query repository method projects a few attributes from the two documents using interface projection.
After some debugging I see that the failure occurs because of this check in org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod:

```
public boolean isQueryForEntity() {
    return getDomainClass().isAssignableFrom(getReturnedObjectType());
}
```

called from `org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.ReactiveAbstractN1qlBasedQueryexecuteDependingOnType()`.

Apparently the document entity is not assignable from the projection interface which is expected.

Here're the prototype classes in question:
First document:

```
@Document
@Data
public class DocMetadata {
    @Field
    private String type;

    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String title;
}
```

Second document:

```
@Document
@Data
public class Doc {

    @Field
    private String type;

    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String metadataId;

    @Field
    private Status status;

    @Field
    private String releaseDate;
}
```

Projection interface:

```
public interface DashboardDocProjection {

    String getId();          // from Doc.id
    String getReleaseDate(); // from Doc.releaseDate
    String getStatus();      // from Doc.status

    String getTitle();       // from DocMetadata.title

}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CouchbaseDocRepository extends
        ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository<Doc, String> {

    @Query("<query to select Doc join DocMetadata projecting some attributes from both>")
    Flux<DashboardDocProjection> getProjection();

}
```

As a workaround, I can make projections work with a separate @Document representing projected attributes and a separate repository for that document type, but it requires more boilerplate code and is not so nice in general. An example mapping looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT META(`doc1`).id AS _ID, META(`doc1`).cas AS _CAS, "
    + “doc2.title as title, "
    + "`doc1`.id as versionId, "
    + "`doc1`.attribute2 as attribute2 "
    + "FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} `doc1` "
    + "JOIN #{#n1ql.bucket} doc2 ON KEYS […] "
    + "WHERE `doc1`._class = "\"<doc1.class>\" "
    + "AND `doc1`.attribute1 = $1 "
    + "AND `doc1`.attribute2 = $2 "
    + "ORDER BY `doc1`.id ASC "
    + "LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4;")
Flux<DashboardEntry> findAll(
    String attribute1Value, String attribute2Value, Integer limit, Integer offset);
```

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem. Another workaround is to use `myReactiveRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().findByN1QLProjection()`. This however returns an `Observable` and forced me to do something like `Flux.from(RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(observable))`. So I think your workaround is the better solution.

Comment: May I ask how your query looks like for your workaround? I need to manually select the class (`SELECT... 'my.package.Name' as _class`) so that the converter is able to map the json to my POJO.

Comment: Added an example of query mapping to the post.